# Simple program considered malware

Tags: c++, audio, malware, antivirus

I'm working on an alarm clock application. I've been testing some things with the following code:

```
FMOD_SYSTEM* sound;
FMOD_SOUND* son;
FMOD_System_Create(&sound);
FMOD_System_Init(sound, 32, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, NULL);
FMOD_System_CreateSound(sound, "alarm.mp3", FMOD_CREATESAMPLE, 0, &son);    
SYSTEMTIME time;
GetSystemTime(&time);

while (!(time.wHour==16 && time.wDayOfWeek==4)) {
    Sleep(10000);
    GetSystemTime(&time);
}

    FMOD_System_PlaySound(sound, son, NULL, 0, NULL);
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                INPUT ip = { 0 };
                ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
                ip.ki.wVk = VK_VOLUME_UP;
                SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
                ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
                SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
            }
```

The idea would be to pu it in the Startup folder so that it launches every time the user logs in, then waits until the specified hour. Then, it would play the sound file using the FMOD library and increase master volume. I know that my way of increasing volume is unorthodox, but I'm just testing for the moment. It works well if executed.
The problem is that my antivirus considers it malware. I've tried it under Avast and Bitdefender with the same results. It's a rather simple code that doesn't even manage files, **how can it be considered a threat?**

Thanks

**Edit:** Forgot to say that I've tested it with and without the master volume managing loop. Therefore, there should be a problem anywhere else...

Comment: "_It's a rather simple code that doesn't even manage files_" Well.. 1) Malicious code doesn't _have_ to manage files, 2) nor does it have to be complicated.

Comment: AV S/W is watching for certain "suspicious" activities to detect dangerous software. Thereby "suspicious" is a stretchable term. Once, I wrote a tool which converted HTML entities (e.g. `&auml;`) to XML entities (i.e. `&#228;`) and reverse (for my personal use). The AV software I was using that days (Avira) was detecting this as dangerous. Why? Due to the table of HTML entities I had built-in? I don't know. I had to remark it as "false-positive". My colleague is writing (Windows) services as part of our productive work - and is struggling with our AV S/W as well. (I often hear him ranting.)

Comment: Every bit of unsigned unknown code is a threat. Add your workspace to the list of excluded items or uninstall antivirus completely.

Comment: @VTT you really wanna tell someone else to uninstall anti virus software? That's very suspect for me. I would also mark it as a false positive.

Comment: Since using ´SendInput´ offers you the ability to do almost whatever you want with the computer, I can understand why the antivirus is suspicious about it.

Comment: If you take a step back and think about any other application that would do this sort of thing; it IS malicious.  Name one other program that isnt' malicious and attempts to change your volume by pressing keys... it just isn't done!

Comment: @UKMonkey I forgot to say that I've also tested without the SendMessage line. It is still detected as malware.

Comment: @VTT Uninstalling A/V to allow an alarm clock to work seems to me a bit too much...

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius 1) File managing is a easy of being considered malware by an A/V and 2) what I mean by simple is that it only loads a sound file and plays it.

Comment: @JuanGM "_File managing is a easy of being considered malware by an A/V_" If it is easy way, why should it be the only way?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Have I ever said it is? You don't get my point... It is easy to be trapped by A/V when you do some kind of FM, I was only saying "this is not my case". I've never said that managing files is THE way to be detected as malware.